# Implementing new feature using SOLID principles in old code

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, solid-principles

I just try to get more into `SOLID` principles but get stuck by implementing new structures in my old (not `SOLID`) code.

I have this `Room.Class`

```
public class Room {
   private String roomCode;
   private String roomDescription;
   // getter/setter
}
```

Now I need to have a translation for the `roomDescription`. I started to create an `interface`

```
public interface ITranslation {    
    String findTranslation();    
}
```

and an `implementation`

```
public class RoomDescriptionTranslation implements ITranslation {

@Override
public String findTranslation() {
    return "translated Room";
}
```

In the already existing code there is a service class which creates some `Rooms` with `codes` and `descriptions`. These `Rooms` are also used in the view (as jsp bean).

The new requirement is to have the translated description on the view.

So for me the question is where I should implement the logic of translation of the existing `Rooms`.

- Should I implement it in the existing serivce class where the `Rooms` are created?
- Or should `RoomDescriptionTranslation` be a field inside `Room`?
- Or should I created a new service class where just the `description` gets translated?

Just need a pointer to go to the right direction.

Comment: As I understood if you add logic for translating, you are adding logic of translation then there are two responsibilities imposed to a class. Which as of now is not having "Single Responsibility". So you can take a call here if you need to create a new class and do something good or just be lazy and add to the existing class.

Comment: Do you want to find the description text using the room's code?

Comment: @SME_Dev I already have a description. But need a translation of it and also need the translated description on the view. (Could also overrie the existing one)

Comment: I would not create any new types, instead add desired functionality to the RoomFactory or any service class that is already there.

Comment: I would refactor the `description` to be a new type, it certainly is not as simple as `String` as of now. And handle all translation in the new type.

Comment: Not related to the question but since this question is speaking about principles, don't start interface names with an `I`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be first or third option, but not the second option in my opinion. I think one important question, in general for designing any class is this:

**For a property *p* and class *C*, is *p* a property of *C*?**

So, in your case the question becomes: is translation a property of Room? Semantically, it sounds that it is not.

Then, you can ask the same question on Room Service class. The answer to that depends on how you defined your service class. Again, another rule that helps to decide whether a property belongs to a class, is this:

**What is one singe word or phrase that describes this class?**

This goes to the very idea of what a class is in OOP and also to S in SOLID. Once, you ask this question and can describe one single purpose for your class, then you can go back and ask the first question, whether certain property belongs to this class or not.

Now, if your service class is such that, "Handle all room related actions" (not saying this is right, but if this is the case) then you can add one more action to it, namely translation. But, if it is not then you may create a new service, translation.

Considering all this, I lean more towards having a new translation service as it looks

1. Something independent
2. Will be easily extendible (compared to other option) like adding more languages
3. Does not require changing existing code

Again, there might be other factors affecting the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a model `TranslatedRoom extends Room` to use only in view this L from SOLID and inside this new model would take care about translations.

Of course if it is possible to refactor service which creates model for views etc.

One more thing (maybe it is S from SOLID) this idea is good if we need to show translated room only in this/these views.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to translate text you should use internationalization solutions which already exist in java.

In your solution you'll create painful maintenance problems and every string which you'll return will be surrounded by `if`.

Comment: Sorry, it does not depend on internationalization. There is a room description like `"deluxe Room"` and this should be translated in another way. Not language.